# How to force a program/shortcut to start mimimized

Tags: windows-7

How can I set a windows application to start minimized mode when it starts

Eg : I want to start firefox in minimized mode every time i click it.

I tried changing the "Normal window" to "Minimized". Sadly, that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Using FireFox 31 on Windows 7 (Pro 64-bit) here's what I discovered.

Setting the shortcut to run it as "Minimized" works as expected, UNLESS FF was in full-screen (Maximized) mode when you closed it last; if so, then it will open Maximized regardless of that shortcut's setting.

Open FF and restore it to a windowed state, and then close it -- it will then respect the Minimized start-up option in the shortcut the next time you try to open it.

Answer (score 0):

For `Firefox` a standard `Windows` method with shortcut properties is known to work correctly.

- Create shortcut to `Firefox`
- Right click the shortcut and go to `Properties`
- Under the `Shortcut` tab in chose option to run minimized
- Apply settings and close the window